# Can anyone explain tf.random_normal and tf.truncated_normal shape argument?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, normalization

I am working with tensorflow and until and unless the arguments were 2 dimensional, I didn't faced any issue but now I came across a syntax

```
tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64])

tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7*7*64, 1024]))
```

and one more

```
tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])
```

And similarly in truncated_normal also.
Can anyone explain the working of these lines and how this is implemented behind the code? It would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: That question doesn't talk about the 4-dimensional shape attribute of the function so how can you mark it duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these functions sample for either a normal distribution or a truncated ( cut at the tips) normal distribution respectively, the shape parameter is used to specify the shape of the resulting tensor ie. how many samples you are going to take from the respective distribution and what shape will they be in.

Anything up to 3 dimensions is easy to picture,

`tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7*7*64, 1024]))` creates a 2D-tensor of shape 3136x1024 of randomly sampled values from a normal distribution.

Similarly, `tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024]))` will create a vector of size 1024 (or a 2D-tensor of size 1x1024)

Finally, `tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64]))` is a bit harder to picture mentally, this results in a 4D-Tensor of size 5x5x32x64.

This could represent a batch of 5 3-D tensors, where the first dimension (the first '5' in this case) will represent the *batch size* of some input data.

Not sure how much detail you're looking for, I'm afraid that's as far as my knowledge goes, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help.